# Bar Chart by Group with an average line

Tags: r, bar-chart

I’m trying to have a bar for each cluster.  I need the height of each bar to be the average within each zip code (based on the population).  I would then like a horizontal dotted line of the average of all zips.

```
    ## Data
df <- data.frame(
zipcode=c("10001","10002","10003","10004","10005","10006","10007","10008","10009","10010"),
 black= c(2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,13,15),
 white = c(6,8,12,14,15,16,14,14,14,22),
 population = c(11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,100),
 female = c(5,11,32,22,31,21,44,11,22,14),
cluster = c("1","2","3","2","2","1","3","3","3","1"))
print(df)

> print(df)
   zipcode black white population female cluster
1    10001     2     6         11      5       1
2    10002     3     8         22     11       2
3    10003     4    12         33     32       3
4    10004     6    14         44     22       2
5    10005     7    15         55     31       2
6    10006     8    16         66     21       1
7    10007     9    14         77     44       3
8    10008    11    14         88     11       3
9    10009    13    14         99     22       3
10   10010    15    22        100     14       1
```

If I am trying to make a bar chart of cluster by %white.
The overall average of whites is 23%, which would be a horizontal dotted line.

The overall average whites of cluster 1 would be 24%
The overall average whites of cluster 2 would be 30.5%
The overall average whites of cluster 3 would be 18%

Comment: The data creation code does not match what `print(df)` outputs. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50882335/add-group-mean-line-to-barplot-with-ggplot2) is relevant.

Comment: You say you want to plot *"the average within each zip code"*. Average of what?

Comment: My bad. Fixed it.

Comment: The other columns, like black, white or female within that cluster.  The average needs to be based on the population not the observation.  So the average whites in row one is 6/11.  Average whites in cluster 1 is (6+16+22)/(11+66+100)=24.8%.

Comment: Got it :https://community.rstudio.com/t/bar-chart-with-dotted-mean-line/43979/2